# Limiting what a team can see and access in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I am very new to managing Azure DevOps. I have two, what are for me related, questions.

When I create a team within a project - either the first default team or a later added team - what determines the users that are available for me to add to the team?

Within a single project, can I create a team that can see its own area path/board work items, but is not able to see the area paths/boards of other teams in the project? I have an outside firm working on the project and I want them to be able to see the work I assign to them, but not all the rest of the work assigned to internal members of the team. Can I do that within a single Azure DevOps project?

Answer (score 0):

When creating a team, you specify the default level of access (I believe it's normally "Contributor").

Work item access can be limited based on area path.

Keep in mind that Azure DevOps permissions have an order of precedence:

- "Allow" means "Allow unless explicitly denied"
- "Not set" means "Deny unless explicitly allowed"
- "Deny" means "Always deny"

So if you have a user in both Team A and Team B, and you set Team B to have a "Deny" permission for something, that means that the user who is a member of both teams will *not* be able to access it.